# Bootstrap table pagination with MySQL and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pagination, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a mysql database which is selecting results where $name = kicked,

this returns several results (usually 50+)

I do not know how to paginate the results - help?

This is the code for my table:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="2">

    <br>

  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Kicker</th>
        <th>Kick Reason</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
        <?php
          $kicks = mysql_query("select * from Kicks where kicked = '$name'");




while($row = mysql_fetch_array($kicks)) 
  {
        echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['kicker'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['reason'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pager" id="myPager"></ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the Mysql `LIMIT` clause. It allows you to select x elements from your table starting at offset y. The offset can be determined by passing a page number parameter to your page.

Pseudo code:

.../page.php?pagenumber=2

```
$iPerPage = 10;
$iOffset = (pagenumber - 1) * $iPerPage;
SELECT ... FROM `kicks` LIMIT $iOffset, $iPerPage;
```

See this [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)